# bootstrap 3.0 button group as nav menu with collapse data-parent

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to have a 4 button menu. When a button is pressed it does not closes the parent. I already tried to put all in one panel but then it goes over 100 % width with one button. And I want to arrange them in one line-
Also how would I make this button group to share the width for each button for 25 % of the screenwidth?

Here is what I have tried. Thanks in advance
http://www.bootply.com/Gkouk5MedC

Comment: **[Why don't you try bootstrap tabs?](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/9ahkr82b/1/)**

Comment: hey this looks very nice. But it seems I cannot include the toggle collapse effect with smooth fade in / fade out. I found this: http://jsfiddle.net/RfsS9/5/ which works find until I put a new accordion inside the navbar-collapse http://jsfiddle.net/RfsS9/165/ it closes all other collapse elements when clicking one accordion link. How would I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

it seems like in bootstrap 3.3.* this example http://jsfiddle.net/RfsS9/165/ won't work. Besides it does not work in bootply either neither in my browsers.

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
<div class="container">
  <div class="navbar-header">
```

Toggle navigation
          
          
          
        
        
          Toggle navigation

```
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
  </div>

  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
   <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">
            Collapsible Group 1</a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
          <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
          sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
          minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
          commodo consequat.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">
            Collapsible Group 2</a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
          sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
          minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
          commodo consequat.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3">
            Collapsible Group 3</a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
          sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
          minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
          commodo consequat.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> 
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  <div id="test2" class="nav-search collapse">
          <div class="search_box">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#">message 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">message 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">message 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">message 1</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-search -->
</div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
```

http://www.bootply.com/oGlDWCaSxx#

Any other chance to have multiple navbars in one line (plus accordion in collapsed navbar?)